# Sum of N-highest number in a series excluding duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I had gone through the thread [Sum up to N-highest value of series](https://superuser.com/questions/571915/sum-up-to-n-highest-value-out-of-a-series) and it's not exactly what I need. e.g.

`=SUM(LARGE(Range;1); LARGE(Range;2); …; LARGE(Range;N))`

The question is if the data set has 5 numbers and i am interested in sum of highest four. For this I've looked through the thread [Sum the first N elements of a column](https://superuser.com/questions/525525/sum-the-first-n-elements-in-a-spreadsheet-column):

`=SUM(OFFSET(AK$1,1,0,AZ1,1))`

There will not be any problem with this, if all the five entries are different. But if there are any 2 entries with same value, then I wish to take one such entry for sum.

In other words, if the 5 numbers are
0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, sum of highest 5 is 15.

For 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, the same code will return the value 16 and i wish the value to be 14 (by omitting the 2 which has repeated second time)

How to achieve this?

Comment: Is it always going to be highest 4 of 5?  Or is it highest n-1 of n? or is it highest 4 of n?

Comment: For the present problem, it was highest 4 of 5. But, its better to generalize as highest n of m,  where n is less than m.

Comment: Updated my answer to include columns, might be able to be cleaned up a bit more, but it's functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, I think I got it:

```
 =SUM(IFERROR((LARGE((IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A5,A1:A5),A1:A5)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:5")))),0))
```

The `INDIRECT("1:X")` specifies the `X` largest numbers.

It's an array formula so CSE <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shft</kbd> <kbd>Entr</kbd>

---

The formula needs to be changed (transposed) if you're working from a **row** instead of from a **column** -

```
 =SUM(IFERROR((LARGE((IF(FREQUENCY(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1),TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)),TRANSPOSE(A1:E1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:5")))),0))
```

Comment: I'm getting highest 5 of 5 (or more values).  Should the indirect use 1:4?  (with the additional clarity added by OP today)?  Otherwise, seems to work great!

Comment: @Madball73 Changing it to 1:x (for top x) or changing the total range A1:Ax should be able to still perform correctly, *I think*

Comment: I missed your second line telling us this, sorry!  Great job.  This one was bugging me.  Works with negatives and zeroes,but not with blanks, but I think that's OK.

Comment: @Raystafarian i have edited the formula for my XLS as SUM(IFERROR((LARGE((IF(FREQUENCY(F2:J2,F2:J2),F2:J2)),COLUMN(INDIRECT("0:5")))),0)) and returned the value 0. I have values ranging from 0 to 5 including fractions.

Comment: @Anil no need to change row to column or include 0, it's making an array to use

Answer (score 1):

If your values are in "range", then this should work:

```
   =SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(range,{1,2,3,4,5})/COUNTIF(range,LARGE(range,{1,2,3,4,5})))
```

Instead of counting multiples only once, it counts each occurrence as Value/TotalOccurences, which has the same net effect.

Comment: I'm not clear if the range can contain **more** than 5 values? - If so this may not work if there are duplicates at the cutoff point, e.g. if you have a range containing these values - `7,7,7,7,7,7,7` - then the above formula returns 5

Comment: @Madball73 If i take 3, 2.5, 4, 4 and 3, it returns the value 9.5. I expect 14.

Comment: Why would it return 14?  both 4 and 3 repeat and are counted once, so top 5 = 4+3+2.5=9.5.  Regardless, it does have the issue that Barry mentioned, so I recommend using Raystafarian's method.